# FromSql(): Query string building from string list to prevent injection

Tags: c#, sql-server, .net-core, entity-framework-core, sql-injection

I'm building an SQL search in EF Core. Microsoft recommends you do not concat string because it leaves the application vulnerable to SQL injection as detailed in Microsoft Documentation: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/raw-sql.

> Always use parameterization for raw SQL queries: In addition to
>   validating user input, always use parameterization for any values used
>   in a raw SQL query/command. APIs that accept a raw SQL string such as
>   FromSql and ExecuteSqlCommand allow values to be easily passed as
>   parameters. Overloads of FromSql and ExecuteSqlCommand that accept
>   FormattableString also allow using string interpolation syntaxt in a
>   way that helps protect against SQL injection attacks.
>
> If you are using string concatenation or interpolation to dynamically
>   build any part of the query string, or passing user input to
>   statements or stored procedures that can execute those inputs as
>   dynamic SQL, then you are responsible for validating any input to
>   protect against SQL injection attacks.

The information that's stored in this database is not sensitive, but obviously I would not like to leave the database vulnerable.

I have a param `List<string> searchTerms` that I need to iterate through and build a query based this list.

I'm going to and the strings together with my SQL query, but I can only see how to do this with concatenation.  Right now my code looks like this.

```
var query = String.Format("SELECT ... where MySqlField like '%{0}%'", searchTerm[0]);

for (int i = 1; i < searchTerm.Count(); i++)
{
    query += String.Format(" and MySqlField like '%{0}%'", searchTerm[i]);
}

var results = context.MySqlTable.FromSql(query);
```

Even though I'm using interpolation, would extra validation be enough here? Am I missing anything?

Is there a linq query that can do the same thing with a list?

Comment: FromSql has an overload that allows you to pass parameters. Why don't you use it?

Comment: By the way, multiple AND conditions on the same field. Probably you need to use OR here.

Comment: @Steve How would I add the params to the FromSql overload based on a list of changing size?

Comment: If you're passing multiple values, have you considered using a Table-valued parameter? If you would prefer to not use a TVP, you could pass a delimited list and use a string splitter like `STRING_SPLIT`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're code should be good enough with a bit of modification:

```
var query = String.Format("SELECT ... where 1=1 ");

for (int i = 0; i < searchTerm.Count(); i++)
{

    query += $" and MySqlField like '%'+{{{i}}}+'%'";
}

var results = context.MySqlTable.FromSql(query, searchTerm.ToArray());
```

Comment: This is exactly what I'm looking for in terms of using a list/array as a string parameter. Can you explain `where 1=1`?

Comment: @ That `1=1` is there as a "dummy" criteria so I can start appending `and ...` from the start of the loop.

Answer (score 1):

I cannot test it at the moment, so I let you know about this approach

```
List<string> ph = new List<string>();
int count = 0;
foreach(string s in searchTerm)
{
    ph.Add($"MySqlField LIKE '%{{{count}}}%'");
    count++;
}

if(count > 0)
    query = query + " WHERE " + string.Join(" OR ", ph);
var results = context.MySqlTable.FromSql(query, searchTerm.ToArray());
```

And while it seems like a string concatenation approach, we can read in the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/raw-sql#passing-parameters)

> While this may look like String.Format syntax, the supplied value is
>   wrapped in a parameter and the generated parameter name inserted where
>   the {0} placeholder was specified.

Comment: No need to test, I'm only looking for the approach. I can test on my own.

Comment: Probably there is something to fix in the wildcard % and the single quotes. Now it looks like that we are building a literal text here instead of a parameter placeholder

Answer (score 1):

There is few options:

1. Pass your values in XML (or JSON if using newer SQL Server) and then write static XML/JSON query.
2. create a temporary table, insert all search values in a temp table and then execute static query.

Comment: Number 2 is clearly the correct answer to this problem.

Comment: Option 3: Use full-text search.

Answer (score -1):

I would recommend looking into LINQ if you're using EF. Using raw string sql is not a very good idea for both security and performance. LINQ provides a robust way to perform queries. Just be careful on how you write your queries as LINQ can over try to over complicate them.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/linq/

EDIT:

I missed the last line of your post. Sorry, the following should help get you on the right track:

```
for (var item in searchTerms) {
    query = query.Where(w => w.MySqlField.Contains(item.Value));
}
```

Comment: I would have done this to begin with, but I wanted to avoid a scenario where I am executing a search through multiple iterations at which point I would have to make sure the results are distinct - it seems like extra unneeded overhead. I'd like to execute a single query if there's any possible way.

Comment: Without more insite into your code, the only help I can offer you there would be to retain the query as an iqueryable before running this foreach (which i realize i forgot the each). It wont process the query until you convert it or force it to with .ToList() or whatever your preferred method is. That way you only hit the database once. As far as making sure your query inputs are distinct, you can use searchTerms.Distinct() with little actual over head. Though you may want to look at your inputs to see why you would have multiples..